# cocos2d ccDrawPoly over the CCSprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, drawing, z-index, sprite

How can I set in cocos2d 1.1 the z-index to ccDrawPoly() to draw this above all the CCSprite(s) in scene?

```
-(void)draw
{
    CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glColor4ub(0, 0, 255, 255);
    glLineWidth(2);
    CGPoint vertices2[] = { ccp(0,0), ccp(0,screenSize.height*0.5), ccp(screenSize.width*0.5,screenSize.height*0.5), ccp(screenSize.width*0.5,0) };
    ccDrawPoly(vertices2, 4, YES);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, all drawing is done with zero zOrder. so, if you want your sprites to be drawn under things your draw manually, you can add your sprites with negative zOrder. for example, instead of using `addChild:` method, you can use `addChild:z:` with z value `-1`.

Comment: z-index ccDrawPoly should be more than 3, in my example

Comment: in this case, create layer, draw all you want in this layer and add this layer with zOrder 3

Comment: mmm... create your own implementation of ccnode or change existing one... just take a look into the CCNode's visit method. It sends visit to all children with negative zOrder, then calls self draw method, then send visit to all children with positive zOrder.

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to accomplish this. Assuming the draw method is overridden in your own subclass of CCNode, then:

- add the drawPoly node with a z order greater than any of the sprite's z order
- add the drawPoly node in a separate layer (or node) whose draw order is higher than the layer with the sprites

If the draw method is overridden in the class containing the sprites as children, you should override the visit method instead. Then first call [super visit] before running the custom draw poly code:

```
-(void) visit
{
    // draw node and children first
    [super visit];

    // draw custom code on top of node and its children
    ccDrawPoly( … );
}
```